# Can I add to the wire length of C9 LED Christmas Lights?

Tags: led, wiring, light

I've found plenty on the topic of shortening C9 LED Christmas Lights, but have not found anything about lengthening a string. I don't want to add any additional bulbs, but rather add some additional wire to transition between areas that I don't want lights (between windows, gutter/facia transitions, etc.).

I plan using the same wire (22 AWG) and the longest run would be about 10' of additional wire on any given strand. Light strands being used are the EcoSmart
50-Light and EcoSmart 100-Light LED Multi-Color C9 Light Set from Home Depot.

Any problems with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Passerby's answer is good. A link to  the lights concerned would not hurt. SOLDER connections, SLEEVE connections. If insurance matters to you then maybe best not done as how do you prove it was not your mod afterwards? Perhaps astoundingly - they WILL find your extension i the smoking ruin of your home (that's the investigators' job and they are good at it. )

Answer (score 1):

Splicing in 20 feet (round trip) of 22 gauge wire will produce a negligible drop on the wire, depending on the current being carried. At 1 Amp, the drop at 120V is less than 1%.

The biggest challenge is making the splice weatherproof. If you do not seal the splice properly, water or snow can get in and cause issues. If both splices are affected, a dead short can happen. To minimize this, use heat shrink, electric grease, and offset the splice so that the two parts are not side by side. Keep in mind, making this wiring change may be frowned upon by your insurance if something happens.